# Joomla 3 - category link breaking if category title contains an ampersand &

Tags: php, html, escaping, joomla3.0

I have Joomla v3.x.x template override that creates an isotope layout with some category filters.

The problem I have is that if an ampersand (&) is put into the title of the category, that particular category filter will not show.

Is the a way to escape or allow the ampersand (&) to show and not break the filter for that particular category?

Code:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');

if (count($this->children[$this->category->id]) > 0 && $this->maxLevel != 0) : ?>

    <?php foreach ($this->children[$this->category->id] as $id => $child) : ?>
        <?php if ($this->params->get('show_empty_categories') || $child->numitems || count($child->getChildren())) : ?>

            <?php $data_name = $this->escape($child->title); ?>
            <?php $data_option = str_replace(' ', '', $data_name); ?>

            <li class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#" data-option-value=".<?php echo $data_option; ?>"><?php echo $this->escape($child->title); ?></a></li>

            <?php if (count($child->getChildren()) > 0) : ?>

                <?php
                $this->children[$child->id] = $child->getChildren();
                $this->category = $child;
                $this->maxLevel--;
                if ($this->maxLevel != 0) :
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('children');
                endif;
                $this->category = $child->getParent();
                $this->maxLevel++;
                ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif;
```

This is the particular line that create the filters from the category titles:

```
<li class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#" data-option-value=".<?php echo $data_option; ?>"><?php echo $this->escape($child->title); ?></a></li>
```

Comment: The category name should be sanitized before being dabbed into the DB.  Did you check the category take entry to see how the & is being saved in DB.  Try comparing the category name after running through htmlspecialchars_decode() or running what you're comparing to thru htmlspecialchars().

Comment: Thanks Brian - is there any way I can do this in the above code when pulling in the title?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely tied to the rendering of the filter select.  Try changing the following line:

```
<?php $data_name = $this->escape($child->title); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php $data_name = htmlspecialchars($child->title); ?>
```

And see if that resolves the issue.